# Go update slice iterating error "does not support indexing"

Tags: go

I'm trying to iterate through slice values and update one or more values, accessing it by index or iterating through them. Then I have the following problem.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Member struct {
    Name, Surname string
    Age           int
}
type Members []Member

func main() {
    members1 := Members{
        {"Bob", "Doe", 30},
        {"Jack", "Doe", 30},
        {"John", "Doe", 30},
    }
    members1.ModifyName()
    members1.ModifyAllNames1()
    members1.ModifyAllNames2()
    fmt.Println(members1)
}

func (members *Members) ModifyName() {

    *members[0].Name = "-"
}

func (members *Members) ModifyAllNames1() {

    for i := 0; i < len(*members); i++ {
        *members[i].Name = "-"
    }
}

func (members *Members) ModifyAllNames2() {

    for _, m := range *members {
        m.Name = "-"
    }
}
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
invalid operation: members[0] (type *Members does not support indexing)
invalid operation: members[i] (type *Members does not support indexing)
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Type `*Members` does not support indexing, type `Members` does.

```
m := make([]Members, 5)
pm := &m

m[:2]     // good
pm[:2]    // bad
(*pm)[:2] // good
```

---

https://go.dev/play/p/CDaBKqB-sqM

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Member struct {
    Name, Surname string
    Age           int
}
type Members []Member

func main() {
    members1 := Members{
        {"Bob", "Doe", 30},
        {"Jack", "Doe", 30},
        {"John", "Doe", 30},
    }
    members1.ModifyName()
    members1.ModifyAllNames1()
    //members1.ModifyAllNames2()
    fmt.Println(members1)
}

func (members *Members) ModifyName() {
    (*members)[0].Name = "-"
}

func (members *Members) ModifyAllNames1() {
    for i := 0; i < len(*members); i++ {
        (*members)[i].Name = "-"
    }
}

func (members Members) ModifyAllNames2() {
    for i := range members {
        members[i].Name = "-"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! I have a question. When should I use the ()? Like (*members)[0] and (*members)[i]...

Comment: *members[0] is interpreted by the compiler as *(members[0]). So first it gets the first element of the slice, then applies the pointer deref. What you want is for it to first deref the slice, then get the element. This can be done with (*members)[0]. It first applies the * to the slice and then indexes.

Comment: Another answer is to make them no longer pointer methods: `func (members Members) ModifyName() {
    members[0].Name = "-"
}`

Comment: Your third function, ModifyAllNames2() does not actually modify the Name field

Comment: This has been fixed. ModifyAllNames2() is now tested.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> func (members *Members) ModifyName() {
>     *members[0].Name = "-"
> }
> ```
>
> `invalid operation: members[0] (type *Members does not support indexing)`

The issue is that of operator associativity and/or precedence, although I couldn't find this specific case explicitly covered within the Golang spec.

The expression `*members[0].Name` appears to be equivalent to `*(members[0].Name)`, so, to get the proper pointer deference, you gotta use a pair of parentheses explicitly around the item that must be dereferenced, as is, `(*members)[0].Name`.